# What does "was born in black and white" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I've heard a song with the words "She was born in black and white". Could anyone say what this phrase means?

Comment: What song? It could mean various things - if we know what the song is, then we can better pin down what the phrase means.

Comment: In Spanish I heard that referring to someone born before color photography was introduced

Comment: "The world didn't turn color until sometime in the 1930s" ;) http://everything2.com/title/The+world+was+black+and+white

Comment: It's poetic imagery, not a standard idiom, so it could have various shades of meaning. Without more context I'd guesss it means *born in to an impoverished environment*. Probably *financially* impoverished, but it could mean an environment lacking in emotional or intellectual stimulation, for example.

Comment: It's a song by KT Tunstall "Suddenly I see"

Comment: Fumble has beautifully explained the correct answer:  **It's poetic imagery, NOT A STANDARD IDIOM**.  (Just unrelatedly, Fumble, I totally disagree with you as to the likely poetic meaning: surely, it likely means *'born with an artistic, elegant, belle-epoque sensitivity, in to a crash commercial modern world!'*  Just to repeat, I love your phrase **It's poetic imagery, NOT A STANDARD IDIOM** which can be used as a standard clarifying answer for many questions here.

Comment: By the way.  It's quite silly that anyone would mark this question down.  It's an excellent question: for a non-native speaker or youth reader, for example, you could easily see that this **"sounds like it could be"** some sort of idiom. (Indeed: it is **very close to** a couple of specific well-known idiomatic phrases.) The phrase deserves exploration as to whether it is indeed an idiom, a turning of an idiom, or indeed if Fumble's phrase perfectly encapsulates the situation. Thanks for the great question, Max.

Comment: Reading the rest of the lyrics of the song from which it derives, "Suddenly I see" by KT Tunstall, it could mean that the girl is so beautiful that she seems born to end up being a model on the pages of a magazine, where many advertisements are in black and white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This quote may shed light](http://sidrahmoizkhan.blogspot.com/2011/04/she-was-born-in-black-and-white.html) on the question:

> She knew she was born in black and white, The hue of this world was
>   not for her.

The meaning would seem to be that the woman in question feels apart from reality as others experience it.